# Is there a quick way to delete/update my Iphone contact list?

Tags: iphone, software-update

On my new SE, I used a software app provided by Verizon to transfer contacts from old 5C to new SE. I did it but now have many duplicates, have to go into each one, age down and delete. Any quicker way?

Comment: Do you use iCloud for your contacts?

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, it looks like the software provided to you by Verizon not only transferred your contacts to your new iPhone SE, but it also duplicated some of them. So you're now asking for a quicker way rather than deleting those duplicated manually yourself.

---

You may follow **two** different paths:

- [Download](https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/cleanup-duplicate-contacts/id513670485?mt=8) **Cleanup Duplicate Contacts** (an app which function is explicitly the one you're looking for) and run it on your iPhone affected by the issue
- [Contact](https://support.apple.com/it-it) **Apple Support** as they may have a quicker and smarter way to help you in such issue related to your contacts list

---

I suggest you to follow the first option before contacting the Apple Support, even though that is a completely working way to solve any issue with any of your Apple related issues.

**P.S.** If you're thinking about contacting Apple, you may find useful the new [Apple Support App](https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/supporto-apple/id1130498044?mt=8) now available for download on the App Store!